# Print activity of android studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to print my layout activity directly with a button, I don't know is neccesary pass activity to PDF format o directly to print.

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xskSh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the root view of your activity as image, do this:

```
    View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),View. MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

And to print:

```
PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(this); // Asume that 'this' is your activity
photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
photoPrinter.printBitmap("print", bitmap);
```

Comment: I have the next problem, A/Bitmap: Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!